# Laravel route model binding does not get ID

Tags: php, laravel, binding, model, routes

I'm learning Laravel 5 and found something that I do not understand. If I put this code to route, than everything goes fine:

```
Route::bind('addresses', function($value, $route) {
    return App\Address::find($value)->first();
});
```

But without it I got the:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong. 1/1 ReflectionException in
>   Container.php line 736: Class Address does not exist

error.

My routes:

Route::model('addresses', 'Address');
Route::resource('addresses', 'AddressesController');

My AddressesController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Address;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AddressesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $addresses = Address::all();
        return view('addresses.index', compact('addresses'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  Address $address
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show(Address $address)
    {
        return view('addresses.show', compact('address'));
    }
```

My question is why I get the error code if I do not bind the ID value directly in my route. Laravel says with RESTful Resource Controller I got the addresses/{address} with ID automatically, but it seems not. Any idea? Thanky for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`Route::model` takes full class name. `Route::model('addresses', 'App\Address');`